# I want to bring configurator records attached with end dated products. (oracle)

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to bring configurator records attached with end dated products and these configurator records should not attached with active products. (oracle)

I made this query but it is showing zero record.

**Here my Query :**

```
select count(*) from (
select conf.**cog_sku_id**,dprd.**product_id**
from core.rh_configurator conf,cata.dcs_prd_chldsku dchldsku,cata.dcs_product dprd
where conf.cog_sku_id = dchldsku.sku_id and dchldsku.product_id = dprd.product_id and (dprd.end_date < sysdate)
and (conf.cog_sku_id = dchldsku.sku_id and dchldsku.product_id != dprd.product_id and (dprd.end_date is null or dprd.end_date > sysdate)));
```

Can any body help?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  You need to edit your question and show the table definitions, sample data, end expected output.  Nobody here can help you without all the details.

Answer (score 0):

I have also modified the query but problem is, those cog skus are also coming in result across whom products are active.

select distinct conf.cog_sku_id from core.rh_configurator conf
where conf.cog_sku_id in (select sku_id from cata.dcs_prd_chldsku where product_id in (select product_id from cata.dcs_product where end_date < sysdate))
and conf.cog_sku_id in (select sku_id from cata.dcs_prd_chldsku where product_id not in (select product_id from cata.dcs_product where (end_date is null or end_date >= sysdate )));

Comment: Still need to modify this query.